# Create from xaml DataGridTemplateColumn column in c#

Tags: c#, xaml

I have short xaml code :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}"></TextBlock>
           </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Category}" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp"></TextBox>
          </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But I dont know how to convert it on c#. I did that: but it dont work, and dont know how add Event to TextBox:

Edit: dont throw exception, but still dont work. Without event.

```
var a = new DataGridTemplateColumn() { Header = "Kategoria", Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star) };
var aa = new DataTemplate();
aa.Resources.Add(1, new TextBlock() { Text = new Binding("Category").ToString() });
a.CellTemplate = aa;
var aaa = new DataTemplate();
aaa.Resources.Add(2, new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox() { Text = new Binding("Category").ToString() });
a.CellEditingTemplate = aaa;
ProjectDataGrid.Columns.Add(a);
ProjectDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Mnemonik", Binding = new Binding("Mnemoniese"), Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star) });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be helpful. I just convert your XAML markup in C# code step by step.

```
DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn
{
    CellTemplate = new DataTemplate
    {
        DataType = typeof(TextBlock)
    },
    CellEditingTemplate = new DataTemplate
    {
        DataType = typeof(TextBox)
    }
};

FrameworkElementFactory CategoryBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
CategoryBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Category"));
templateColumn.CellTemplate.VisualTree = CategoryBlock;

FrameworkElementFactory CategoryTextBox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
CategoryTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("Category"));

CategoryTextBox.AddHandler(KeyUpEvent, new KeyEventHandler(TextBox_KeyUp));
templateColumn.CellEditingTemplate.VisualTree = CategoryTextBox;

ProjectDataGrid.Columns.Add(templateColumn);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have problem with take method. Because when it is public i get method but cant create delegate. But when is protected cant get method. When is protected method = null, when is public delegat throw the access is not compatible with the delegate. How this method should look. I was trying use other owerload GetMethod but to no avail.

Comment: Ok i found how get nonpublic method, but delegate keyup still dont work. Error: cannot bind to the target method because its security signature or transparency does not match the delegated type's security signature or transparency

Comment: Maybe it can help:MethodInfo method= this.GetType().GetMethod("TextBox_KeyUp", 
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

Comment: I added it. I changed "Delegate KeyUp = Delegate.CreateDelegate(actionType, this, method);". But still throw now on "CategoryTextBox.AddHandler(KeyUpEvent, KeyUp);" with exception: "“Specified cast is not valid”"

Comment: It happen when I try create more object like this.